# Unable to get the exact position of the track player when the app is in background using react-native-track-player

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

I want to call an API with the current position of the track player when my app is in background whenever I try to stop the track player from the notification panel. Also how can I kill the track player when I kill the app.

I want my track player to get the current and correct position where it is at whenever I try to stop the player from the notification bar and the app is in background. Also, I want to kill the track player when I kill the app. I tried getting the app state and also getting the current position but still it gives me the position at which I switched to the background and not the position when my app is running in the background